# What is the process for retrieving the precise start and end times of a job schedule execution in Pentaho 6.1 server?

Tags: java, pentaho

I am utilizing `Pentaho BI server 6.1` and have established several scheduled subscriptions that run automatically at specified times.

My objective is to retrieve the precise start and end times of each job's execution.

To achieve this, I am currently developing a Java plugin that will log the start and end times of every schedule run in Pentaho. This involves implementing a custom listener that integrates with the Pentaho scheduling framework and captures the necessary information.

I have successfully completed the following steps:

1. Set up the development environment using Eclipse.
2. Created a new Java project to contain the custom plugin code.
3. Added the necessary Pentaho dependencies to the project's classpath for Pentaho v6.1.
4. Packaged the plugin into a JAR file.
5. Deployed the JAR file, containing the custom plugin, to the directory "/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/quartz".
6. Configured the Pentaho Server to utilize a custom listener by updating the appropriate configuration files, namely "quartz.properties" and "/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/pentaho.xml".

Here's the skeleton of the listener class I've implemented:

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.quartz.JobListener;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class SubscriptionExecutionListener implements JobListener {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(SubscriptionExecutionListener.class);

    public void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
        logger.info("Job execution started at " + new Date());
    }

    public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {
        logger.info("Job execution finished at " + new Date());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    public void jobExecutionVetoed(JobExecutionContext arg0) {
    }
}
```

However, I am encountering an issue where my custom plugin class is not being called during the execution of schedules, resulting in no output in the log files. I suspect that I may have overlooked something or might need to modify the code to override methods of the actual JobListener class. Could you please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue or suggest any necessary code modifications?